# How to open and close a popup window after it's completely loaded (in a loop)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have something like this for my own little bookmarklet:

```
jQuery('#fire').click(function() {
for (counter=0; counter<links; counter++) {
 var currentLink = jQuery('body').find('.imageWrap:eq('+counter+')').attr("href");
 var newWindow = window.open(currentLink);
    /* and here close the popup when the site is completely loaded */
}
});
```

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Using `newWindow.onload = newWindow.close();` should work. It's binding the close function of the window to the onload event handler (which fires when the page has finished loading).

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you need to access the newly window object created's onload handler like this:

```
url = '_blank';

newWindow = window.open( url );
$(newWindow.document).ready(
   function() { alert('loaded'); }
);
```

But if think there will be browser restrictions if you're opening URL from external domains.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also do: $(newWindow.document).ready(function() { ... }) just to keep it within the jquery syntax and all the goodies it brings.